# “Old school” Virtual Oscilloscope SWF

Tags: oscilloscope

There used to be a seriously good virtual oscilloscope that I used in my classroom which happened to utilize shockwave flash, but is now no longer accessible due to flash no longer being supported.

https://www.virtual-oscilloscope.com/

If you ever used this, you know what I mean… would anyone happen to know a workaround so that I can continue to use this simulation?

Comment: Did you consider to set up a virtual machine, for example with an old Windows?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about EE

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently on a mobile device, so I can't check the website myself, but:

Emulating old software in the context of education is (sadly?) a common problem. For flash, ruffle.rs is the usual tool. You might want to install the ruffle browser extension, or if that doesn't work, extract the flash file URL by looking at the website's source code, download it and try to run it in ruffle manually.

For a day more simplistic emulated oscilloscope: https://automatisierung.fh-aachen.de/virtuallab/scope/dist/